# check if unbound checkedit was checked in Master-Detail XtraGrid

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

i have use this code to add unbound checkedit controle to detail gridview

```
this.gridView11.OptionsSelection.MultiSelectMode  =  DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridMultiSelectMode.CheckBoxRowSelect;
this.gridView11.OptionsSelection.MultiSelect = true;
```

how I can check if checkedit was checked or not, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

When you enable the [built-in CheckBox column](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/16439/Controls-and-Libraries/Data-Grid/Focus-and-Selection-Handling/Multiple-Row-Selection-via-Built-In-Check-Column-and-Selection-Binding), checked states of these column cells are synchronized with the current selected rows. Thus, you can catch the moment when a row is selected by handling the [GridView.SelectionChanged](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView.SelectionChanged.event) event. If you need to access selected rows, use the [GridView.GetSelectedRows](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView.GetSelectedRows.method) method. If you wish to determine if a particular row is selected or not, use the [GridView.IsRowSelected](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView.IsRowSelected.method) method.

Refer to the [Multiple Row and Cell Selection](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/711/Controls-and-Libraries/Data-Grid/Focus-and-Selection-Handling/Multiple-Row-and-Cell-Selection) help article for more information.

Comment: thanks, Svetlana for your help, But how can I determine the checkedit column name, because i want to make a loop that fire on click of a button and add date in date column where checkedit was checked, i try to use the name that apper when move the mouse on the header of the column but i get 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' this is my code             GridView subgView3 = (GridView)gridView3.GetDetailView(gridView3.FocusedRowHandle, 0);

           
            bool unboundData = (bool)subgView3.GetFocusedRowCellValue("Sélection");

Comment: To obtain this column name, use the static GridView.CheckBoxSelectorColumnName property. For instance, 
var column = gridView1.VisibleColumns.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == GridView.CheckBoxSelectorColumnName);